# Passing data from parent to sub-query

Tags: mysql, sql

Im am trying to create a query that joins on some data for each row of the main query, but I do not know how to get around the issue "Unknown column 'cm.index' in 'where clause'". How can I pass a column value of the parent query row to the sub query?

Each row in the parent query has an index integer. I want to count the number of `channel_members` that have a consumption index greater than the index of each message.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B83CK_O33-cQVk1EVXJ5QUlaYVE/view?usp=sharing) is a sample db

```
SELECT read_count.*, cm.*
FROM   chat_messages as cm
JOIN (SELECT b.chat_channel_id, Count(b.chat_channel_id) AS members_read 
    FROM   channel_members b
    WHERE  b.consumption_index >= cm.index 
    GROUP  BY b.chat_channel_id) read_count 
ON cm.channel_id = read_count.chat_channel_id
WHERE cm.channel_id=5;
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: That's a JOIN, not a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subquery that you're joining with is not a correlated subquery, so you can't pass columns from the main query into it, they have to be related in the `ON` condition.

You should change the subquery to include `cm.index` in the grouping. Then you can join on that.

```
SELECT cm.*, SUM(rc.members_read) AS members_read
FROM chat_messages AS cm
JOIN (SELECT chat_channel_id, consumption_index, COUNT(*) AS members_read
      FROM channel_members
      GROUP BY chat_channel_id, consumption_index) AS rc
ON cm.channel_id = rc.chat_channel_id AND rc.consumption_index >= cm.index
WHERE cm.channel_id = 5
```

Or you could do it as a real correlated subquery, which goes in the `SELECT` list.

```
SELECT cm.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM channel_members AS b
    WHERE b.chat_channel_id = cm.channel_id AND b.consumption_index = cm.index) AS members_read
FROM chat_messages AS cm
WHERE cm.channel_id = 5
```